# What happened to the job postings formerly shown on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, jobs

When I first began visiting Stack Overflow several years ago, the site would show job postings on the page similar to how *The Overflow Blog*, *Featured on Meta*, and *Hot Meta Posts* are displayed presently in the top right corner. I recall there was also a dedicated page where users could search and filter all jobs.

Why is this functionality no longer present on the site?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/sunsetting-jobs-developer-story

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Jobs" part of Stack Overflow was shut down on March 31st, 2022, as per this MSE post: [Sunsetting Jobs & Developer Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293/2422776).